# Can you recommend a podcast on OOP & Design?

Tags: oop, podcast

Can you recommend me a web site providing pod-casts focused on OOP & Design?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This may be more advanced then you are after but best to get started on the right track. If you don't understand everything in here don't worry too much.

This is Scott Hanselman talking with Uncle Bob describing SOLID

http://www.hanselminutes.com/default.aspx?showID=163

You can also look at the resources avalable on Object Mentor http://www.objectmentor.com/videos/video_index.html

Have Fun!

Comment: http://www.codingblocks.net/ is a really engaging podcast covering stuff like design patterns.  .net centric, also related subjects like security, licensing, SQL.

Answer (score 4):

software engineering radio. They have been doing it for a long time and they are good.

http://www.se-radio.net/

Comment: Thanks, this is also a good one!

Answer (score 2):

I agree with David above and would like to include Dime Casts.Net series on S.O.L.I.D. The series is for the C# Visual Studio folk but think it's an invaluable set of videos. Check it out here: http://dimecasts.net/Casts/ByTag/SOLID%20Principle